# Where to post "First name, surname and gender of someone from an unfamiliar country"?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Could anyone please help me find for the right SE site to post the following question?

> Suppose you receive an e-mail from someone from a foreign country, and
>   you are not familiar with their language and culture. They sign their
>   message as
>
> > Yours sincerely,
> >
> > XXXXX YYYYY
>
> but you don't know which is their first name/surname (conventions
>   about which one should come first [vary across languages and sometimes
>   across contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name#Name_order)), nor you can tell which gender they are (should I
>   reply with "Dear Mr./Ms. XXXXX"?).
>
> What resources (websites?) would you use to tell the first name and
>   the surname apart, and to determine their likely gender?

Comment: `names.stackexchange.com`? But seriously though, I don't think such site exists.

Comment: I've had luck with just using Google to find this. Type one of the names in and you can usually find *something* about its origin and use. I did this a lot when trying to determine gender at a previous job, which was a required field in our system but a lot of forms we accepted did not have a space to indicate it. Cut down on the number of Unknowns I had to type in.

Comment: Generally people will sign their name in a way they're okay being addressed. And you may have no choice but to do that sometimes, since many names don't actually indicate gender, e.g. Carey, Casey, Jessie, Layne, Taylor, or Angel. So while there may sometimes be good reasons to want to know these things, other times it may not be necessary to know, and I'd suggest considering if that's the case for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a question may arise in [professional](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) or [academic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) environments, in which case it can be asked on the relevant site. In fact, I think it might already be answered.

Comment: The e-mails I get are indeed from an academic context. Sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

There's no site on the Stack Exchange network for that.

If you know which culture they are from, then you can usually find the answer with a little search. No Stack Exchange post needed.

If you don't know which culture they are from, then it's going to be a list question - "Japanese: family name first. English: family name last". And so on. Off-topic on most (possibly all) SE sites.

Only in the rare case that you know what culture they are from, and that culture has wildly confusing rules about this that aren't easily answered, is Stack Exchange an option. Then you'd check if there was a [culture].stackexchange.com .

Outside the Stack Exchange network, I'd see what I could find on Wikipedia.

Comment: Clarification: I was not looking for a SE website to help me find out more information about a given first name/surname. I was asking for a general solution, which your answer gives. Thanks!

Comment: @Arek'Fu You're welcome... but that is not what Meta.SE is for. The "site-recommendation" tag is meant to find the appropriate site _on SE_.

Comment: @SLBarth I understand that. I asked for help to find a SE site where I should post the general question above. You directly answered the general question, instead of directing me to a SE site.